# Issues filtering items in SwiftData with Query and Filter

Tags: swift, predicate, swift-data

I am attempting to implement SwiftData and I am getting errors but only after running the code and the errors are inside the expansion of the macro 'Query'

[image]

The errors are:

Attribute 'private' can only be used in a non-local scope

Cannot convert value of type 'PredicateExpressions.Equal<PredicateExpressions.KeyPath<PredicateExpressions.Variable, String>, PredicateExpressions.KeyPath<PredicateExpressions.Value, String>>' to closure result type 'any StandardPredicateExpression'

Cannot find '_existingItems' in scope

Below is my code:

```
func addOrUpdateItems(_ files: [FILE]) {
   let container = try? ModelContainer(
       for: FILE.self
   )
   
   let context = ModelContext(container!)
   
   for item in files {
       // Use a query to fetch items with the same ipswName
       @Query(filter: #Predicate<FILE> { $0.fileName == item.fileName })
       var existingItems: [FILE]

       if let existingItem = existingItems.first {
           // Update the existing item with the new data
           existingItem.fileName = item.fileName
           existingItem.downloadUrl = item.downloadUrl
       } else {
           // If the item doesn't exist, insert it into the context
           context.insert(item)
       }
   }

   // Save the context after processing all items
   try? context.save()
```

}

This is my @Model

```
import Foundation
import SwiftData

@Model
class FILE: ObservableObject, Identifiable, Hashable {
    
    var fileName: [String]
    var downloadUrl: URL
    var sha: String
    
    init(fileName: [String], downloadUrl: URL, sha: String) {
        self.fileName = fileName
        self.downloadUrl = downloadUrl
        self.sha = sha
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(sha)
    }
}
```

I tried following https://www.swiftyplace.com/blog/fetch-and-filter-in-swiftdata and going through Apples documentation and https://www.swiftyplace.com/blog/fetch-and-filter-in-swiftdata

Any help would greatly appreciated. I'm sure I am doing this wrong but I am attempting to access and store data outside of a SwiftUI view.

Comment: You can't use `@Query` inside a function (or anywhere outside a view), use a `FetchDescriptor` instead. Off topic but is `fileName` really an array and don't use all caps for a type name.

Comment: Adding to my first comment, when looking at your code it's clear it won't even compile so if you got a runtime error it wasn't with the code you have posted in your question.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I fixed the provided snippets. I can't share my official code since it's used by my company. I also compiled it and provided a screenshot of the errors inside the at Query.

Comment: Query only works at the View struct level and a Model shouldn’t be an ObservableObject. Try some of the SwiftUI tutorials or WWDC videos. If the tutorials you quoted did any of these things they missing key differences between new and old.

Comment: As everybody mentioned - the `@Query` wrapper is misused.
However, the actual issue is likely with `#Predicate` macro.
When you provide a comparison closure, it will not work with captured structured values.
So
`let predicate = #Predicate { $0.value == item.value }`
won't work, but this will -
`let value = item.value; let predicate = #Predicate { $0.value == value }`